# Convert HH:MM:SS string to moment

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, momentjs

I am using full calendar and I am trying to see if an event created is overlapping with the lunch breaks which I have defined as part of business hours. This is my code

```
function isCalendarEventOverlappingBusinessHour(event) 
{
    var evts = businessHoursArr;

    for (i in evts) 
    {
        var start_moment=moment(evts[i].start, 'MMM DD').format();
        var end_moment=moment(evts[i].end);

        if (event.start.isBefore(end_moment) &amp;&amp; event.end.isAfter(start_moment))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

I am not able to compare the event start and business hour start since in business hours, the time is defined in string format as `08:00:00`. I want to convert it into a moment so that I can compare the times. Can anyone suggest a method?

My event is in the following format:

```
events.push({
    id: guid(),
    title: eventTitle,
    start: moment(date), 
    end: moment(date).add(defaultTimedEventDuration,'hours'),
    stick: true,
});
```

And my businesshoursarr looks like

```
{
    dow:[1,2,3,4,5]
    start:08:00:00
    end:12:00:00
},
{
    dow:[1,2,3,4,5]
    start:13:00:00
    end:17:00:00
}
```

Comment: It is just that your format string is wrong. For time, it will be HH:mm:ss.
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/

Comment: @kra3 sorry I meant HH:mm:ss. Ignore the caps in title

Comment: var start_moment=moment(evts[i].start, 'HH:mm:ss')

Comment: why do you need to do this? If you set `selecConstraint` to "businessHours" as described in the docs, the calendar will not let anyone select time periods outside the businessHours at all. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/selectConstraint/

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest `moment(value, 'HH:mm:ss').valueOf()` which will return an integer and you could just compare numbers at that point.

It'd also help if you provided an example of what `businessHoursArr` and `event` look like.

Update: Taking your code and making a few modifications, this should give you the general idea.

```
function isCalendarEventOverlappingBusinessHour(event) {
   var evts = businessHoursArr;
   var overlapping = false;
   var dayFormat = 'YYYYMMDD';
   var secFormat = dayFormat + 'HH:mm:ss';
   var eventStartDate = event.start.format(dayFormat);
   var eventEndDate = event.end.format(dayFormat);

   for (i in evts) {
       var start_moment = moment(eventStartDate + evts[i].start, secFormat);
       var end_moment = moment(eventEndDate + evts[i].end, secFormat);

       if (event.start.isBefore(end_moment) && event.end.isAfter(start_moment)) {
           overlapping = true;
           break;
       }
    }

    return overlapping;
}
```

Comment: @Philomath I updated my answer with some code to help lead you in the right direction

Comment: I tried your code,though I am not getting any errors, it is not working as expected. Overlapping is always false.  This is my output Businee hours:1517524200000,1517538600000

event times:1517571900000,1517575500000

Businee hours:1517542200000,1517556600000

event times:1517571900000,1517575500000

Comment: @Philomath I updated again. Since using just HH:mm:ss, moment will use today's date. The code should use the year,month,day of the comparison and just append the selected HH:mm:ss

Comment: yes I understood your logic.But even now overlapping is false. Actually as per example of business hours array, there should be no booking between 12 pm to 1pm. Ideally we should be checking if the event time lies in that gap

Comment: Looking at the console output in the fiddle, the code works: https://jsfiddle.net/2zx257yt/

Unless you're expecting the dow logic to be taken care of OR the events.push({ start | end }) moment values aren't parsed correctly

Comment: What does the value of the ```date``` field look like when you're pushing to the events array?

Comment: I have used the date in dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view)  and its the format Fri Feb 02 2018 08:45:00 GMT+0000